# Access permissions for SSL certificates acquired with Let's encrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I got `SSL certificates` with `Let's encrypt` and established `HTTPS communication` with `docker-compose's nginx container`.
I was able to connect successfully, but I was worried about the access permissions of the folder.

The environment is `amazon linux 2`, and the SSL certificates obtained by Let's encrypt is stored in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/`.
Here, the access permissions for `the live folder` are as follows.

```sh
drwx------ 3 root root 47 Nov 9 02:12 live
```

So, it seems that the `ec2-user` user **cannot access** it.
To use the SSL certificates, I copied the pem files to the appropriate folder with `root privileges`, and was able to connect successfully, but is this the right way?

This time, I copied the pem file to `/home/ec2-user/ssl` like below.

```sh
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user    93 Nov  9 05:32 ssl
```

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ssl]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user   93 Nov  9 05:32 .
drwx------ 7 ec2-user ec2-user  163 Nov  9 05:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     1854 Nov  9 03:14 cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     3749 Nov  9 03:14 chain.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     5603 Nov  9 05:32 fullchain.pem
-rw------- 1 root     root     1708 Nov  9 03:14 privkey.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  692 Nov  9 03:14 README
```

By the way, when I accessed the file `/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/` from which I copied the file, and did `docker-compose up -d`, I got the following error.
It is probably an error of **access permissions**.

```
[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

The README said **DON'T MOVE**.

---

docker-compose.yml -> nginx volumes

```
volumes:
...
- /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com:/etc/nginx/certs #error
# - /home/ec2-user/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs #ok
...
```

---

default.conf

```
server {
server_name www.example.com;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The nginx must be started as root so it can read certs of root user. Then the nginx will start workers on behalf of www-data user.
It's similar too Apache httpd
[How does Apache access SSL certs created by root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383678/how-does-apache-access-ssl-certs-created-by-root-user)
Speaking about where to place certs: there is no a clear answer https://serverfault.com/questions/259302/best-location-to-keep-ssl-certificates-and-private-keys-on-ubuntu-servers

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

The pem files in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/` were **symbolic links**.
So I should have mount at `/etc/letsencrypt/`.

The real pem files are in `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/www.example.com/`.

---

docker-compose.yml -> nginx volumes

```
volumes:
...
- /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
...
```

---

default.conf

```
server {
server_name www.example.com;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.net/privkey.pem;
...
}
```